# How would I remove the text from the output of this reduced array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array:
`['Online Learning', 'Online Learning', 'Online Learning', 'Communications', 'Communications', 'Intranet']`

I'm using the below to find the frequency/occurrences of each value in this array:

```
const catsReduced = cats.reduce((acc: any, currentValue: any) => (acc[currentValue] = (acc[currentValue] || 0) + 1, acc), {});
```

This outputs:

```
{Online Learning: 3, Communications: 2, Intranet: 1}
```

How would I edit the above reducer to show just:

```
[3,2,1]
```

(as number types).
I'm not sure I can be clearer, but please do say if more is required.

Comment: [`Object.values(catsReduced)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: If you're targeting versions older than ES2017 and do not want to change the target to ES2017 or later, [`Object.keys()`](https://tsplay.dev/w1GA8m) along with `map` can also help. Using this ts won't complain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an object to store the counts, you can directly push the counts into an array.

`1-` iterate over the array using `reduce` and count the ocurrences of each element.

`2-`extract the values (the counts) from the resulting object using `Object.values()`.

`3-` the resulting array contains the counts of each unique value in the same order they appear in the original array.

```js
const cats = ['Online Learning', 'Online Learning', 'Online Learning', 'Communications', 'Communications', 'Intranet'];

const counts = Object.values(cats.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
  acc[currentValue] = (acc[currentValue] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(counts);
```

`Edit:` if typescript is giving you that error try changing your lib compiler option to `es2017` or later which can be found probably in your `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["es2017"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Should have said I'm using TypeScript:
I'm getting an error with the Object.values
Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2017' or later.ts(2550)

Comment: @NightTom, you write "Try changing the lib compiler option". Who are you telling that? Sure, you have to have support for ECMAScript 2017 (which has been out for over *six* years! -- an eternity in IT).

Comment: I'm assuming that is his error msg

Comment: @trincot - where did I write that?

Comment: @NightTom in your first comment to this answer

Comment: ahhh - that's output from Visual Studio Code. Not from me.
Anyway changing the compiler isn't working anyway.

Comment: It works anyway - there seems to be something wrong with my linter - it's overly sensitive. The accepted answers works perfectly. UPDATE: Mandy8055 - I've used Object.keys this is accepted. UPDATE AGAIN! Object.keys does not show the numbers, it shows the text. So can't be used in this case.

Comment: oh ok, so changing the lib was not necessary then?

Comment: @NightTom no it isn't. See here: https://tsplay.dev/w1GA8m

Comment: No it wasn't necessary - the code works but there is something overly sensitive about the linter I'm using.

Comment: @mandy8055 - YES! Perfect, works brilliantly. I'll upvote your comments.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method to get the frequencies is to use `Object.groupBy`, then get the length of each array. (Note that this shortens the code at the cost of wasting some more memory.)

```js
const cats = ['Online Learning', 'Online Learning', 'Online Learning', 'Communications', 'Communications', 'Intranet'];
const res = Object.values(Object.groupBy(cats, x => x)).map(x => x.length);
console.log(res);
```